# Mercury XAMPP sending lots of email automatically

Tags: xampp

We have configure the XAMPP in server, But we are facing an error like it's automatically generated lots of mail and sending  itself.

Please suggest us to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "honeypot" field (textarea), hide it with CSS, and check that it's empty.

If not, it's likely a bot. Kill the request and ban the IP.